# Dynamically created iframe does not recognize jQuery inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the following code that dynamically loads user entered html/js into a iframe to execute it:

```
function compile(s)
{
  s = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"><\/script><\/head><body>' + s + '<\/body><\/html>';

  document.getElementById("ifrm").src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(s);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  compile("<script>$(document).ready(function(){console.log('lol');});<\/script><p>Test<\/p>");
});
```

Using this code I get the error message *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*. What is happening?

Comment: I just noticed that when I use a CDN like https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js, it works as expected. Why can't it use the local file? The path is 100% correct since it is copy pasted from the parent.